# Rasterio S3 read: does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name

Tags: gdal, rasterio

I am unable to read data from S3 using rasterio.

This is the public resource I am trying access which is successful when using AWS CLI
https://registry.opendata.aws/deafrica-sentinel-1/

```
import os
import boto3
import rasterio
from rasterio.session import AWSSession
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(override=True)

boto3_session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=os.getenv("aws_access_key_id"), aws_secret_access_key=os.getenv("aws_secret_access_key")) 
session = AWSSession(session=boto3_session, region_name="af-south-1", requester_pays=True)

file_list = [
    r"s3://deafrica-sentinel-1/s1_rtc/S26E028/2022/11/24/0582A2/s1_rtc_0582A2_S26E028_2022_11_24_VV.tif",
    r"s3://deafrica-sentinel-1/s1_rtc/S26E028/2022/11/24/0582A2/s1_rtc_0582A2_S26E028_2022_11_24_VH.tif"
]
with rasterio.Env(session):
    # Read metadata of first file
    with rasterio.open(file_list[0]) as _src_:
        meta = _src_.meta
        print(meta)
```

The error:

```
RasterioIOError: '/vsis3/deafrica-sentinel-1/s1_rtc/S26E028/2022/11/24/0582A2/s1_rtc_0582A2_S26E028_2022_11_24_VV.tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
```

Versions:
Rasterio - 1.2.10,
GDAL - 3.4.2,
boto3 - 1.24.89

Comment: Were you able to accomplish this? I'm facing the same issue with gdal 3.6.0 and rasterio 1.3.4

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67812512/rasterio-does-not-exist-in-the-file-system-and-is-not-recognized-as-a-support